# Переливание кнопки c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Работаю с WinForm C# и возник такой вопрос: можно ли сделать что бы кнопки в программе плавно меняли цвета по порядку как радуга? Просто открываю программу и кнопки начинают с красного цвета плавно переходить в оранжевый, потом желтый и т.д.? Такое возможно сделать в WinForm? Если да, то как?

Comment: Поставить таймер и по событию таймера менять цвет. Если нужна смена цвета как в радуге, то лучше использовать цветовую  модель HSV

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко а можете привести пример? таймер это понятно, перенес на форму, указал тик к примеру в 1 секунду, а как цвета плавно менять?

Comment: HSV задаётся 3 параметрами: тон(оттенок), насыщенность, яркость. Яркость и насыщенность будут постоянными, а вот тон будет меняться. Но BackgroundColor работает с цветами в RGB. Вам нужно лишь найти или написать функцию перевода из HSV в RGB. Сама формула перевода есть здесь https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_(цветовая_модель) К сожалению, сейчас не могу написать ее. Но функцию такую легко найти в гугле

Comment: Для плавного изменения сделать тик поменьше и соответственно, изменение параметра h уменьшить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал, плавно меняет цвет на рандомный, вот пример того что получилось:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            timer1.Interval = 20;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        float step = 0;

        Color currentColor = Color.DarkGreen;
        Color targetColor = Color.LightBlue;
        Random rnd = new Random();

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (step >= 1f)
            {
                step = 0;

                int R = rnd.Next(0, 255);
                int G = rnd.Next(0, 255);
                int B = rnd.Next(0, 255);
                currentColor = targetColor;
                targetColor = Color.FromArgb(R, G, B);
            }
            int mixR = (int)(currentColor.R * (1f - step) + targetColor.R * step);
            int mixG = (int)(currentColor.G * (1f - step) + targetColor.G * step);
            int mixB = (int)(currentColor.B * (1f - step) + targetColor.B * step);
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(mixR, mixG, mixB);

            step += 0.03f;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто сделайте анимированное gif-изображение, типа такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И назначайте эту картинку кнопкам:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap("rainbow.gif");

button1.Image = bmp;
button2.Image = bmp;
```

Всё! Кнопки переливаются радугой.

Comment: В вашем случае цвета меняются, а не переливаются

Comment: @МишаковМаксим - на создание этой гифки я потратил пару минут. Можно сделать гифку с плавными переходами. Впрочем, обычно я предпочитаю код, а не возню с редакторами, поэтому в реале сделал бы примерно так, как в другом ответе.